# Apache camel Aggregation

Tags: apache-camel

I am using aggregator to aggregate exchanges to a list and then pass that list for batch insertion to database. Once its inserted into first table then all objects in list are modified and then send to another db. The issue i am facing while doing this is that sometime an object which was sent by aggregator as one element in list for insertion earlier is also sent again in next list with modified value.
The Aggregator policy i am using is :

```
public class ArrayListAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {
public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
    Object newBody = newExchange.getIn().getBody();
    ArrayList<Object> list = null;
    if (oldExchange == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        list.add(newBody);
        newExchange.getIn().setBody(list);
        return newExchange;
    } else {
        list = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(ArrayList.class);
        list.add(newBody);
        return oldExchange;
    }
 }
}
```

And the route for same is :

```
    <routeContext id="coreCdrRoute" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route errorHandlerRef="CoreErrorHandler" id="coreEngineRoute">
        <from
            uri="activemq:queue:{{coreEngine.queue}}?concurrentConsumers={{core.consumer}}" />
        <log loggingLevel="DEBUG"
            message="Message received from core Engine queue is ${body}"></log>
        <multicast>
            <pipeline>
                <setHeader headerName="CamelRedis.Command">
                    <constant>RPUSH</constant>
                </setHeader>
                <setHeader headerName="CamelRedis.Key">
                    <constant>CoreCdrBatch</constant>
                </setHeader>
                <setHeader headerName="CamelRedis.Value">
                    <simple>${body}</simple>
                </setHeader>
                <log loggingLevel="DEBUG" message="Adding to redis value : ${body}"></log>
                <to uri="spring-redis://localhost:6379?serializer=#stringSerializer" />
            </pipeline>
            <pipeline>
                <unmarshal ref="gsonCoreEngine"></unmarshal>
                <bean beanType="com.bng.upload.processors.GetCdr"
                    method="process(com.bng.upload.beans.CoreEngineEvent,${exchange})" />
                <transform>
                    <method ref="insertionBean" method="finalCoreCdr"></method>
                </transform>
                <aggregate strategyRef="aggregatorRef" completionInterval="300000">
                    <correlationExpression>
                        <constant>true</constant>
                    </correlationExpression>
                    <completionSize>
                        <simple>${properties:core.batch.size}</simple>
                    </completionSize>
                    <to uri="mybatis:batchInsertCore?statementType=InsertList"></to>
                    <log message="Inserted in masterCallLogs : ${in.header.CamelMyBatisResult}"></log>
                    <multicast>
                        <pipeline>
                            <choice>
                                <when>
                                    <simple>${properties:coreEngine.write.file} == true</simple>
                                    <setHeader headerName="path">
                                        <simple>${properties:coreEngine.cdr.folder}</simple>
                                    </setHeader>
                                    <bean beanType="com.bng.upload.processors.SaveToFile"
                                        method="processCore(${exchange})" />
                                    <log
                                        message="Going to write ivr cdrs to file : ${in.header.CamelFileName}" />
                                    <to uri="file://?fileExist=Append&amp;bufferSize=32768"></to>
                                </when>
                            </choice>
                        </pipeline>
                        <pipeline>
                            <transform>
                                <method ref="logCounter" method="callConferenceLogs(${exchange})"></method>
                            </transform>
                            <choice>
                                <when>
                                    <simple>${body.size()} != 0</simple>
                                    <to uri="mybatis:callConfCounter?statementType=InsertList"></to>
                                </when>
                            </choice>
                        </pipeline>
                    </multicast>
                </aggregate>
            </pipeline>
            <bean beanType="com.bng.upload.processors.RedisImpl" method="removeOnInsertion(CoreCdrBatch)" />
            <log message="Reached end of transaction for CoreEngine successfully" />
        </multicast>
    </route>
</routeContext>
```

I am unable to debug what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: Dont do one giant big route. Split up your route into smaller routes and link them together with direct endpoints. And test each individual routes separately also.

Comment: As suggested by Claus,i broke up the route in smaller steps and tested it again. But still getting the same issue. After removing aggregator,and instead using a list,i am not facing the above issue.